# How to convert numerical strings inside a mixed list of list to int (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion, integer

how do I convert all the numerical strings, inside a list of list that contains both alphabetical, and numerical strings, into an integer?

My Output:

```
[['69', ' Test', 'Results'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', '420', 'F']]
```

Intended Output:

```
[[69, ' Test', 'Results'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 420, 'F']]
```

Note that my code reads a CSV file. Thanks everyone

```
def get_csv_as_table(a, b):
s = False
import csv

with open(a) as csv_file:
    file_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=b)
    member = list(file_reader) 

    print(member)

print ("Enter filename: ")
a = input()
print ("Enter the delimiter: ")
b = input()
get_csv_as_table(a, b)
```

Comment: How about `str.isdigit()`?

Comment: I tried using that yes, but im having trouble operating since its a list of lists :(

Comment: `[[int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in lst] for lst in lists]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to achieve this. The only minor downside to this is that you will be creating a new list for this instead of modifying the existing list.

```
my_list = [['69', 'Test', 'Results'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', '420', 'F']]

filtered_list = [
    [int(item) if item.isdigit() else item for item in sub_list]
    for sub_list in my_list
]
```

If you want to edit the list **in-place**, you can use traditional for-loop. The following code will edit the existing list without creating a new list. This could turn out to be useful in case you have a large list.

```
my_list = [['69', 'Test', 'Results'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', '420', 'F']]

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for j in range(len(my_list[i])):
        if my_list[i][j].isdigit():
            my_list[i][j] = int(my_list[i][j])
```

`str.isdigit()` checks if a given string is a number or not. An important note to keep in mind is that, it does not work for floating-point numbers, just integers. Once the condition passes, the item is converted to integer.

Comment: Yessss, very nice. Thanks alot my dude! that helped a lot

Comment: If this answer seems helpful, you can accept and upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

Yoy have to combine 2 levels of list-comprehension and use `str.isdigit()`

```
values = [
    [int(val) if val.isdigit() else val for val in row]
    for row in values
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with 2-level list comprehension and `int()`+`.isdigit()` power combo in list comprehension ;-)

```
l=[['69', ' Test', 'Results'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', '420', 'F']]
l=[[int(y) if y.isdigit() else y for y in x] for x in l]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[69, ' Test', 'Results'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 420, 'F']]
```

`.isdigit()` only works on string representation of pure integers, In case if you have floats too then replace '.' to nothing ;-)

```
l=[['69', ' Test', 'Results'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', '420', 'F']]
l=[[float(y) if y.replace('.','').isdigit() else y for y in x] for x in l]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[69.0, ' Test', 'Results'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 420.0, 'F']]
```

Comment: Thanks alot my dudes :) Youre a legend